# how to get rid of connection refuses from Oracle instance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-rac

We have Oracle 11g RAC databases having 5 different databases.All of sudden one database like XXXDB was refusing new connectons and all the old connections are in hung state. there was more CPU and IO consumption happend. For that we restarted Oracle Instances and rectified the problem.

What actually we need to do if that situation happens without shutting down Instances of particular DB

Comment: why didn't i get reply on my question.Isnt it added to right group.If it is,Please forward it to right group or else tell me the reason why it is downrated my question

Comment: There are a lot of reasons this can happen.  First you need to find a way to troubleshoot the problem when it happens.  Try to logon as SYS, sometimes only that user can connect to the database.  Do you have any specific error messages, or did the connections just hang indefinitely?  Has this happened more than once?

Comment: Yes ,Connections are hung at that time..Please let me know how to solve without node Down

Comment: Is SYS able to connect?  Some reasons other users hang is if some resource is being used.  Check DBA_RESUMABLE, see if there are suspended sessions, perhaps because a query is using up all of the temporary tablespace.  If if there is a guaranteed restore point but not enough flash space.  Or if the audit trail is full and there's not enough space to audit new logons.  (Although only the first problem would be solved by a restart, the second two problems should persist even after the node was restarted.)